# Hadoop MapReduce: Read a file and use it as input to filter other files

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I would like to write a hadoop application which takes as input a file and an input folder which contains several files. The single file contains keys whose records need to be selected and extracted out of the other files in the folder. How can I achieve this?

By the way, I have a running hadoop mapreduce application which takes as input a path to a folder, does the processing and writes out the result into a different folder.

I am kind of stuck with how to use a file to get keys that need to be selected and extracted out of other files in a specific directory. The file containing keys is a big file so that it can not be fit into the main memory directly. How can I do it?

Thx!

Answer (score 2):

If the number of keys is too large to fit in memory, then consider loading the key set into a bloom filter (of suitable size to yield a low false positive rate) and then process the files, checking each key for membership in the bloom filter (Hadoop comes with a BloomFilter class, check the Javadocs).

You'll also need to perform a second MR Job to do a final validation (most probably in a reduce side join) to eliminate the false positives output from the first job.

Answer (score 1):

I would read the single file first before you run your job. Store all needed keys in the job configuration. You can then write a job to read the files from the folder. In your mapper/reducer `setup(context)` method, read out the keys from the configuration and store them globally, so that you have the possibility to read them during `map` or `reduce`.

Comment: If the number of keys is large, consider using the DistributedCache or the -files generic option, and then loading the keys into memory in the mapper setup stage

Comment: @Christian: how can I make them global? What do you mean with storing all needed keys in the job configuration? how can I achieve this?